# Excel graph format pane missing

Tags: vba, excel, graph, pane

Some time ago, I opened an old excel file with a macro. Then I lost many functionalities of excel, like context menus, pivot table field lists pane etc. I've solved many of them with vba codes, but I have not been able to solve this one yet:

I cannot open graph format panes (the ones that appear on the right when you right click a chart element "xxx" and click format "xxx" ...).

I've already tried excel options and found no solution there. Also, in my previous research to get context menus back, I've found a solution using vba codes. Therefore, I guess this will have a similar solution. The problem is that I could not find the right vba class, method or function to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved  it.

First, I have listed all the names of CommandBars in a sheet using the code below:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim bar As CommandBar
i = 0

For Each bar In Application.CommandBars
  i = i + 1
  Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = bar.Name    
Next
```

This was not necessary, I just wanted to learn the names of CommandBars.

After some trial and error, I have found out that the code below does the job:

```
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Enabled = True
```

The code from the previous answer

```
Application.CommandBars(140).Enabled=True
```

probably does the same thing but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:
Credits to Michael Fowler from Expert Exchange
Here's the [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28608804/Formatting-window-menu-missing-in-Excel-2013.html#a40587626)

```
Sub ShowAllToolbars()
       'loop variable
       Dim i As Integer

       ' Loop through the total number of toolbars.
       For i = 1 To Application.Toolbars.Count

           ' Show each toolbar.
           Application.Toolbars(i).Visible = True
Application.CommandBars(140).Enabled=True
       ' End of loop.
       Next i

   End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Alok for quick reply.

I have seen the link you mentioned, but I could not get this code to work. It gives this error message: "Method 'visible' of object 'toolbar' failed."

Also, I tried other methods mentioned in the link with no success. User JDido mentioned that the code `application.CommandBars(140).Enabled=True`
worked for him/her but I was not able to get a result.